# Tensorflow Model detects only 1 class

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to recognize my fist and palm.

So I follow the Tensorflow Object Dection API

But I could see my model recognizing only one palm

I adjusted the number of images in the palm and fist to be the same.

I also modified the label file, generate_tfrecord, ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.

I want to train the model to detect 2 classes, but after training it recognize only 1 class

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the NUM_CLASS in ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config file and correctly need to match the generate_tfrecord and labelmap.pbtxt.
For your needs:

`NUM_CLASS = 2`  #this must be changed in config as well as the code which you are using to load the trained model.

The config must be like this:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: "fist"
}
item {
  id: 2
  name: "palm"
}
```

*generate_tfrecord.py:*

```
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'fist':
        return 1
    elif row_label == 'palm':
        return 2
    else:
        return None
```

I think this will be working fine for you.